# Python 2.6: How to access base class descriptor field hidden by derived class?

Tags: python, super, descriptor

I have a descriptor storing data in host object's dictionary.
And I have fields of this descriptor in class hierarchy with the same name:

```
class ADescriptor(object):
    def __init__(self, keyname='descr'):
        self.keyname = keyname

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
        return getattr(obj, self.keyname, 8192 )

    def __set__(self, obj, val):
        setattr(obj, self.keyname, val)

class A(object):
    f = ADescriptor('keyA')

class B(A):
    f = ADescriptor('keyB')

b = B()
b.f = 'b'
print super(B,b).f
super(B,b).f = 'a'
```

Last line doesn't work:
super(B,b).f = 'a'

Why get works and analogous set doesn't? 
Can I set A's f in a more elegant way than A.**dict**['f'].**set**(b,'a')?

---

Corrected:

In a form given in my initial post A.f evaluates to keyname-named property of A (missing) or default 8192 - nothing to do with it. That's why I used A.**dict**['f'] - to exclude **get** call.
Minor modification was required to let A.f be evaluated into needed ADescriptor instance:

```
def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
    if not obj:      #return descriptor itself if no bound object given
        return self
    return getattr(obj, self.keyname, 8192 )
```

In this case `A.f.__set__(b,'a')` works.
But it's still ugly!
@BiggAl offered property solution is not good for my needs - I would need to wrap all my descriptors in properies.

Answer (score 1):

Surely `A.f.__set__(b,'a')` would work if `A.__dict__['f'].__set__(b,'a')` works?
And then even `A.f.b = 'a'` aught to work, although you might have to specify it as a property if my memory serves me.

---

See the history to see a massive brainfart...

```
>>> class ADescriptor(object):
    def __init__(self, keyname='descr'):
        self.keyname = keyname
    def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
        return (self.keyname, getattr(obj, self.keyname, 8192 ))
    def __set__(self, obj, val):
        setattr(obj, self.keyname, val)

>>> class A(object):
    f = ADescriptor('keyA')


>>> class B(A):
        f = ADescriptor('keyB')


>>> a, b = A(), B()
>>> print (a.f, b.f, A.f, B.f)
(('keyA', 8192), ('keyB', 8192), ('keyA', 8192), ('keyB', 8192))
>>> b.f = 'b'
>>> print (a.f, b.f, A.f, B.f)
(('keyA', 8192), ('keyB', 'b'), ('keyA', 8192), ('keyB', 8192))
>>> A.f = 'a'
>>> print (a.f, b.f, A.f, B.f)
('a', ('keyB', 'b'), 'a', ('keyB', 8192))
>>>
```

This is what you get right? ( I changed the `__get__` for debugging, it should be changed back to how you had it)

What were you trying to do with super?

Comment: Thanks BiggAl, it worked, at least you gave me the right direction.

Comment: @tuvastamata : good to hear it, if this answers your question please can you mark it as such? Otherwise please elaborate what more you need?

Comment: @BiggAl, Minor modification was required to let A.f be evaluated into needed ADescriptor instance:
    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        if not obj:      #return descriptor itself if no bound object given
            return self
        return getattr(obj, self.keyname, 8192 )
In this case A.f.b works perfect, no property required!

Comment: @BiggAl, poor formatting here, I put details in my initial post

Comment: @tuvastamata Brilliant! It's always good to try and get your interfaces to be as simple as possible (i.e. get it to use `__get__` and `__set__` implicitly) you might find that without using a property the `__get__` works but the `__set__` doesn't under certain obscure circumstances; if it works here though it's good to avoid the more arcane side of python...

Comment: @BiggAl, possibly this is some super feature - only `__get__` works in super produced proxy, now I remember I saw something about it in docs - property would be needed to solve this problem. But A.f.b + returning descriptor's self on no-object `__get__` solves the issue

Comment: @BiggAl, I forget to check where A.f.b = value writes yesterday. And it is totally wrong place.

Comment: @tuvastamata please elaborate.

Comment: @BiggAl `A.f.b=value` just sets b property on A.f object, does not call `f.__set__`

Comment: @tuvastamata I thought so - and if you change it to use a property?

Comment: @BiggAl, if to use properties, there is no reason to use descriptors. In my case I will have too much properties, `A.f.__set__` is better.

Comment: if you create a function that returns a property you can always use decorators.

Comment: @tuvastamata sorry I was a little confused. what were you trying to do with super?

Comment: @BiggAl, I need to get A's f on b object. `super(B,b).f == A.f.__get__(b)`, but it's impossible to assign throw super - only `  A.f.__set__(b,'a')`. Note this works only with my later get modification, otherwise `A.__dict__['f'].__get__` is needed

Comment: @BiggAl, if to use properties, then to use them directly. Also a metaclass is an option... But it's more complicated than `A.f.__set__(b,'a')`

Comment: @tuvastamata so what you want is a nice way of saying b.f = A.f? but when I do that using the definitions above I get `('keyB', ('keyA', 'a'))` - I take it what you want is to get `('keyB', 'a')` or `('keyA', 'a')` ?